# How to calculate boundary layer thickness?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing, efficiency, performance-calculation, boundary-layer

So I have a flat plate with a surface of 7sqm and an aspect ratio of 12 with air blowing straight at it (like a wing) at a speed of 50km/h. I would like to manually calculate the thickness of the laminar boundary layer at the trailing edge of the plank.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the [Blasius solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasius_boundary_layer) for the laminar boundary layer.

There are three measures of boundary layer thickness -- the plain thickness, the momentum thickness, and the displacement thickness.  There are equations for all three available.

Comment: thank you, I used the 99% method I found on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_layer_thickness#The_bounded_boundary_layer_description